# Is it possible to add ajax to the struts2 tags ,textfield or checkbox in jsp page using DOJO ? if yes how?

Tags: struts2

Is it possible to add ajax to the struts2 tags ,textfield or checkbox in jsp page  using DOJO ? if yes how ?

Or if not what library should i use to apply ajax to single textField ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the [Struts2 jQuery Plugin](http://code.google.com/p/struts2-jquery).

This contains an [AJAX Textfield Tag](http://code.google.com/p/struts2-jquery/wiki/TextfieldTag) for Struts2.

Answer (score 1):

To use DOJO, First of all add the DOJO tag directive like this

```
<%@ taglib prefix="sx" uri="/struts-dojo-tags"%>
```

and then add the following line in the head part of your JSP

```
<sx:head debug="false" cache="false" compressed="true" />
```

Then listen the event from the struts tag on which you want to apply the ajax as follows

```
<s:radio label="Radio" name="rad" list="list2"  
                onchange="show_details();" ></s:radio>
```

catch this event in javascript and publish the topic as follows

```
<script>
    function show_details() {
        dojo.event.topic.publish("show_detail");
    }
</script>
```

And listen the published topic on the same JSP by struts div tag

```
<sx:div showLoadingText="false" id="details" href="DetailAction" theme="ajax"
    listenTopics="show_detail" formId="frm_demo"></sx:div>
```

The argument "show_detail" in the script call and div tag's listenTopics attribute should match exactally. That div will listen the topic and pick up the href attribute and matches with the action in struts.xml

```
<action name="DetailAction" class="ajaxdemo.action.DetailAction">
            <result>/Detail.jsp</result>
</action>
```

It will call your action class `ajaxdemo.action.DetailAction`

and selects the values according to the value given by radio button and renders the following JSP Detail.jsp

```
<%@ taglib prefix="s" uri="/struts-tags"%>

<s:if test="lstList != null">
    <s:select list="lstList"></s:select>
</s:if>
```

and places the out put where you have defined your  div tag in your main JSP

You can also view the detail example on [java-tale.blogspot.com](http://java-tale.blogspot.com/2010/07/using-dojo-for-ajax-call-in-struts-20.html)